# Building debian package with compiled source

Tags: package-management, qt, debuild

Is there a way to just build the debian package with binary file already compiled? 
I want just to put my application into a package because I don't want it to do a step I already done.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with `dpkg-deb` tool if you prepare control files correctly. Extract some other package with `dpkg-deb` to see what's needed.

Other option: if you know CMake and CPack then it's also possible to write a CMake script to pack anything into a deb.